# Not able to connect IBOutlet in XCode 13

Tags: xcode, xcode13

**My setup**: I am using Mac Book Pro M1. I have been using XCode 12.5 Beta 3. I also installed XCode 13 recently.

**Problem**: I created the simple project in XCode 13 with just 1 image view, 1 label, and 1 button. I open ViewController and trying to drag the connection from the label to ViewController to create a connection. But it is not adding the connection. It shows that line but simply not adding the IBOutlet. The same is happening with ImageView. Although, being able to add IBAction for my button. I clean the project also and tried creating another project too. The same issue exists.

Now I launch XCode 12.5 Beta3 and create the same project there. I am able to add IBOutlets there.

Not sure where the problem lies. I added the same in Apple forum.